# Rails 4: Add mail attachment as remote .pdf file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf, ruby-on-rails-4

Result which I want to get, is add file, from remote url, which generates already `*.pdf` file.

My mailer code

```
def invoice(partner, invoice)
    @invoice = invoice
    attachments["invoice.pdf"] = open("http://127.0.0.1/invoice/#{invoice.id}.pdf").read
    mail :to => partner.email, :subject => "Invoice to partner"
end
```

But this code returns error:

```
Invalid argument - http://127.0.0.1/invoice/14.pdf
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't have the server making an http request to itself to render a page!  It has all the resources it needs to make the pdf file.

I don't use prawn, i use acts_as_flying_saucer, which is a rails wrapper for the flying_saucer java app, but i suspect it works a similar way: you should probably (if you're not already) use a rails "wrapper" for Prawn -  it should give you some methods you can use in your controller to render out a pdf.

In acts_as_flying_saucer, for example, i would make a pdf like this:

render_pdf :template => "path/to/a/template.html.erb", 
  :layout => "flying_saucer.html.erb",
  :pdf_file => File.basename(temp_filename)

This will build the pdf in my /tmp folder, and i can then attach it to an email if i want, or send it back to the user with send_file or whatever.

A rails wrapper for Prawn will give you a similar command.  Have a look at prawnto or prawn-rails, or, if you're already using a rails wrapper gem/plugin, read the api.

Answer (score 4):

You need pass path to file on your project like this:

```
def invoice(partner, invoice)
  @invoice = invoice
  attachments["invoice.pdf"] = File.read("path/to/you/file.pdf")
  mail :to => partner.email, :subject => "Invoice to partner"
end
```

***update:***

I propose first to create this file and then apply to the letter, because the file when sending encoded in `Base64`. For example:

```
class MyMailer < ActionMailer::Base

  def invoice(partner, invoice)
    @invoice = invoice
    add_pdf!
    mail :to => partner.email, :subject => "Invoice to partner"
  end

  private

  def add_pdf!
    file = some_method_what_generate_and_save_pdf
    attachments["invoice.pdf"] = file.read
  end
end
```

Comment: But then it won't be dynamic file. I need to send dynamic .pdf to clients.

Comment: your `pdf` dynamic generate?

Comment: Yes. I use prawn to format that view. Its show.pdf.prawn behind `http://127.0.0.1/invoice/14.pdf` url.

Comment: Yes, I already tested that way with saving file and it works, but the result I want to archive is that it take generated from URL and attaches it to mail